# How do I make sure the child element doesn't react to the parent element's event with v-btn in vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js, v-btn

I created 4 buttons dynamically and added custom properties to the buttons.
Whenever I press the button, I check the event and try to use the added attribute value.
If I check the browser developer tool, there is a SPAN tag under the button tag,
so when I click the SPAN tag part, the properties of the SPAN tag are read.
Clicking outside of SPAN tag is OK. How can I get only btn click event?

```
<v-row>
    <v-col v-for="(num, index) in getButtonCount" :key="index">
        <v-badge bordered color="error" :content="num" overlap left>
        <v-btn
            color="warning"
            width="130px"
            height="40px"
            dark
            @click="solveQuestion"
            :answer="answer[index].isTrue"
        >
            {{ answer[index].desc }}
        </v-btn>
        </v-badge>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Below is the converted html tag in developer tools.

```
<button type="button" class="v-btn v-btn--contained theme--dark v-size--default warning" answer="true" style="height: 40px; width: 130px;">
    <span class="v-btn__content"> Testing
    </span>
</button>
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate more on what exactly you're doing! the use case is not clear to be able to give you the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want only the button even to fire but not it's parent use the `stop` event handler

[This section of the Vue docs is what you require](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)

So, assuming that button is nested inside another click event you can do this:

```html
<v-row>
    <v-col v-for="(num, index) in getButtonCount" :key="index">
        <v-badge bordered color="error" :content="num" overlap left>
        <v-btn
            color="warning"
            width="130px"
            height="40px"
            dark
            @click.stop="solveQuestion"
            :answer="answer[index].isTrue"
        >
            {{ answer[index].desc }}
        </v-btn>
        </v-badge>
    </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

Happy Coding